# ASP.NET Query Multiple Tables With MobileServiceClient or IMobileServiceTable

Tags: asp.net, linq, azure, azure-sql-database, mobileserviceclient

I have an ASP.NET application which is using IMobileServiceTable and MobileServiceClient to pull the data from Azure database. I am trying to execute a query with inner/outer joins but dont find a way to query my database.
I understand I can weite ADO.NET style code but wanted to explore what are my other options, if any. The current implementation in the application is using C# and MobileServiceClient.
I am trying something like this but getting error

Error   CS1936  Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'IMobileServiceTable'.  'Join' not found.

```
var query = from a in aTable
                        join am in amTable on a.id equals am.aid
                        join m in mTable on am.mid equals m.id
                        select new { a.id, m.mNote };

            foreach (var amNote in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\" is owned by {1}", amNote.id, amNote.mNote);
            }
```

Your help will be appreciated.
Thanks,
Paraclete

Comment: What type is aTable, and how the used classes are designed ?

Comment: aTable is a class in Models directory and all properties are JSON properties which in turn correspond to columns of Azure SQL Server database.